# How to Prevent Accidental App Exit w/in Android Fragments/Activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-event, back-stack

How Do I Prevent Accidental App Exit w/in Android?

IE: When the he/she presses the back button and reaches the last activity in the BackStack, show a toast to ask if the user wants to exit using the onBackPressed() method.

Also, It needs to function with backStacks for fragments.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality can easily be implemented by overriding main activity's onBackPressed() method. In this example when user presses back button then the app will display a toast for 4 seconds on which time a new back press terminates the app immediately.

[ref](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/back-button-behavior.html)

You can put it in a BaseActivity that extends Activity like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
    . . .

    /**
     * Prevent accidental app exit by requiring users to press back twice when
     * the app is exiting w/in 4sec
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", 4000);
        toast.show();
        this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      } else {
        if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
      }
      super.onBackPressed();
     }
    }
    . . . 
}
```

**EDIT: ADDED FRAGMENT BACKSTACK COMPATABILITY**

For use to detect the last fragment in a bacstack whos application is solely using fragments, I strongly suggest putting your dispatchKeyEvents in a BaseActivity class and implementing the above method like so:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int backCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    . . .

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && backCount == 0) {
                    onexitNotify();
                }else {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
                return true;

            default :
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }

/**
 * Prevent accidental app exit by requiring users to press back twice when
 * the app is exiting w/in 8sec
 */
    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

    public void onexitNotify() {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 8000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", 8000);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

*If you're using 2.0+, onBackPressed() simplifies the amount of code needed so onKeyDown() is not needed.

Per androd patterns recomendation:

> Some applications prompt user when it is about to exit. This seems to
>   be particularly common with game apps. This practice is not
>   recommended in normal applications. A confirmation prompt would
>   disrupt user's normal workflow. Even in games using this option should
>   be very carefully considered.

Comment: `onBackpressed` was introduced in API level 5 whilst keydown has been since API Level 1. Moreover API level 5 is Android 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can check when the back key is pressed in the main activity of your app. You can then show user an alertdialog for a confirmation to exit.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {          
        checkExit();             
        return true;
    }       
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}

private void checkExit()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   //take actions here accordingly as the user has pressed yes
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });      
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();       
}
```

Comment: It is the same amount of code instead of using backpressed I am using keydown. the rest of it is for creating an alertdialog. toasts can be missed depending upon your target audience. Alertdialog is there on the screen waiting for further action.

Comment: per android patterns recomendation: Some applications prompt user when it is about to exit. This seems to be particularly common with game apps. This practice is not recommended in normal applications. A confirmation prompt would disrupt user's normal workflow. Even in games using this option should be very carefully considered.