# NPE on Android BackStackEntry for onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I'm trying to get the back-stack count of the fragments loaded in the activity. The idea here is if the getBackStackEntryCount returns '0', run my onexitCheck() method to worn/ask the user to exit or not but I am getting a NPE at line 70 where it gets the getBackStackEntryCount().

I cant figure out what I have wrong.  Please take a look at my methods and add a correction in your answer. Thnx.

```
public class RegulatoryDiscription extends Fragment {
. . .
}
. . .
//THE NPE STARTS HERE-->
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    int bs = backEntry.getId();

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (bs == 0) {
            onexitCheck();
        }
    }

    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

    public void onexitCheck() {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Press back again to close this app", 4000);
            toast.setDuration(4000);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: NPE is probably on backEntry.getId(), because backEntry is null

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this:

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
```

Should become this:

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
```

Because the count returns 1 for one entry, 2 for two entries, etc; but the entry's index starts at 0.

Comment: Do you ever add anything to the back stack? You can always add this `if(backEntry != null)` before trying to access it.

Comment: I created a better way to do this see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955165/742030).  Thnx

Comment: you need to call fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str);

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the way to do this and I got it to work. I also needed it to function on all fragments so I can reuse my method.  Take a look at a SO question that I [edited here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940726/742030) on how I did it.